# MongoDB $elemMatch for Date

Tags: php, mongodb

This is my data structure

```
...
{
    transactions: [
        {
            show: true,
            updated_at: ISODate("2016-09-16T06:25:54.047Z"),
            created_at: ISODate("2016-09-16T06:25:54.047Z"),
        },
        {
            show: false,
            updated_at: ISODate("2016-09-16T06:25:54.047Z"),
            created_at: ISODate("2016-09-16T06:25:54.047Z"),
        },
        ...
    ]
},
...
```

Here is my code to find count of documents which has at least transaction `{ show: true, created_at: $lt or $gt }`

but I got "0" everytime.
When I remove created_at this code is ok.
How should I do?

```
/**
 * @var $mongoDb \MongoDB\Collection
 */
$mongoDb = \DB::getMongoClient()->selectDatabase('my_db')->selectCollection('packages');

$count = $mongoDb->count([
        'transactions' => [
            '$elemMatch' => [
                'show' => true,
                'created_at' => [
                    '$lte' => new MongoDate(time())
                ]
            ]
        ]
]);
var_dump($count);
```

Comment: Finally I got  this solution change MongoDate to MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime